# Passing an NSString to another view controller crashes the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, extern

I have the following code where I am passing the value of buttonString (an `NSString`) to another view controller. the app crashes when `buttonString = imageName;` is set and then called on the other view controller.

in the .h file of the FirstViewController before the @interface:

```
extern NSString* buttonString;
```

in the .m file of the FirstViewController before the implementation:

```
NSString* buttonString = nil;
```

and here's the code:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%d.png", selectNum + 1 ];
NSLog(@"imageName is %@", imageName);

[buttonImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:imageName]];

buttonString = imageName;

NSLog(@"buttonString %@", buttonString);
```

the problem arises in the `SecondViewController` when this is called:

```
NSLog(@"button Message is %@", buttonString);
```

if I remove the     `buttonString = imageName;` from the `FirstViewController` then the app doesn't crash.

thanks for any help.

Comment: why you are again declaring buttonString in .m file like NSString* buttonString = nil;

Comment: I thought I had to do this. It won't compile if I remove that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `buttonString` is pointing to a released object.

From your code segment, imageName is an autoreleased NSString. When you say `buttonString = imageName;` it just points `buttonString` to the same address as `imageName`. After this method is over, `imageName` gets released and so does the memory to which `buttonString` was pointing too.

This is why the app crashes when you refer to `buttonString` in NSLog.

Ideally, you shouldn't be sharing data using global variables like this in Objective C. But if you just want to make this work you need to allocate memory to `buttonString` when it's used first. Make sure you do release it when it is of no use later.
**NOTE: It still will be a bad way to do things.**

Comment: thanks! if the NSString changes depending upon which image is selected, should it then be an NSMutableString?

Comment: If you use a NSString, you will have to keep alloc-ing/dealloc-ing new memory for every change.

Comment: how would I keep this in memory so it's not autoreleased? Like this:     NSMutableString *buttonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    
    buttonString = imageName;

Comment: Yep. Also use setString method (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/setString:) to replace the value of this string whenever you need to.

Comment: @hanumanDev Also, if it worked, it would be great if you can accept the answer :)

Comment: of course. i wouldn't forget about that :) I'm still trying to figure it out.